# Why a mutex can be locked by two threads?

Tags: c, multithreading, mutex

My C program has three threads `A`, `B`, and `C` that share some buffers. Each buffer is protected by a mutex, and each thread has to lock the mutex before writing/reading a buffer.

`A` writes the buffers, and `B` and `C` reads the buffers. The main function creates `A`, waits until it locks the first buffer with `pthread_mutex_lock()`, and then creates `B` and `C`, so that the buffers are always written before being read.

- main.c

```c
#define mutex_lock(mutex, buff_num)        log("wait on buff[%d]\n", buff_num);  \
                                           printf("pthread_mutex_lock returns %d\n", pthread_mutex_lock(mutex));   \
                                           log("buff[%d] locked\n", buff_num)
    
#define mutex_unlock(mutex, buff_num)      log("releasing buff[%d]\n", buff_num); \
                                           pthread_mutex_unlock(mutex);           \
                                           log("buff[%d] released\n", buff_num)

...
typedef struct
{
    pthread_mutex_t  lock;
    char             data[MAX_DATA_LENGTH];
} buff_t;

uint8_t A_thread_ready = 0;
buff_t buff[NUM_BUFF];
...

int main()
{
    ...
    for(int i=0; i<NUM_BUFF; i++)
    {
        if (pthread_mutex_init(&buff[i].lock, NULL) != 0)
        {
            pthread_exit(NULL);
        }
    }
    ...
    status = pthread_create(&tid[0], NULL, &A_thread, NULL);
    if ( 0 == status)
    {
        break;
    }

    do
    {
        nanosleep(&t1, &t2);
    } while (0 == A_thread_ready);

    status = pthread_create(&tid[1], NULL, &B_thread, NULL);
    if ( 0 == status)
    {
        break;
    }
    ...
}
```

- a.c

```c
...

extern uint8_t A_thread_ready;
extern buff_t buff[NUM_BUFF];

...

void* A_thread(void* arg)
{
    uint8_t write_buff = 0;
    ...
    mutex_lock(&buff_p->lock, write_buff);
    buff_p = &(buff[write_buff]);
    A_thread_ready = 1;
    while(1)
    {
        ...
        mutex_unlock(&buff_p->lock, write_buff);
        write_buff++;
        write_buff %= NUM_BUFF;
        mutex_lock(&buff_p->lock, write_buff);
        buff_p = &(buff[write_buff]);
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

- b.c

```c
...

extern buff_t buff[NUM_BUFF];

...

void* B_thread(void* arg)
{
    uint8_t read_buff = 0;
    ...
    mutex_lock(&buff_p->lock, read_buff);
    buff_p = &(buff[read_buff]);

    while(1)
    {
        ...
        mutex_unlock(&buff_p->lock, read_buff);
        read_buff++;
        read_buff %= NUM_BUFF;
        mutex_lock(&buff_p->lock, read_buff);
        buff_p = &(buff[read_buff]);
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

When running the program, however, from the printed logs, it seems that after `A` locked a buffer, `B` was able to lock this same buffer.

It did something, and released the buffer. After some time `A` released this buffer. I checked the return value of each `pthread_mutex_lock()` call and it was always 0 (successful). What else should I check to find the cause of this problem?

Comment: Need a [mcve] for us to help. A mistake or misunderstanding is happening somewhere...

Comment: Sorry for the oversimplification. I actually used macros for mutex lock/unlock (updated the code). When lock a mutex, the three logs always appeared uninterrupted: I saw the log before the printf() in the macro, the printed 0 (from pthread_mutex_lock()), and the log right after this printf().

Comment: Please don't change the question when you've gotten an answer addressing the issues in the question you actually asked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At first glance I'm deeply concerned about this code:

```cpp
    mutex_lock(&buff_p->lock, read_buff);
    buff_p = &(buff[read_buff]);

    while(1)
    {
        ...
        mutex_unlock(&buff_p->lock, read_buff);
```

It sure looks like you lock some mutex stored in a structure at `buff_p->lock` (buffer 1's lock), then you **change** `buff_p`'s value with `buff_p = &(buff[read_buff]);`, and then you unlock **some other mutex**: the mutex at `buff_p->lock` (buffer 2's lock).  Presumably those are different locks on completely different buffers.

Comment: These two lines (mutex_lock and buff_p assignment) were swapped when I put them in here. They should be what you suggested.

Comment: @fiedel The answer is a reflection of the question as it was. You may accept the answer or reject your own question. Changing your question after you've gotten an answer to it isn't nice. Ask a new question in that case.

Comment: @TedLyngmo The error appeared with two lines swapped (as in the code blocks now). Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @fiedel Ok, then accept this answer and ask a new question properly. Suggestion only. You are free to just leave this open if you wish.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Sounds good. I'll post a new one. Thanks.